# Add a uiview programmatically between two textfields which was created on xib with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have created a xib and added a segmented control on top than i added 4 textfields below with using vertical spacing constraints.

I want to add a uiview between first and second textfields when i will click on segmented control button. 
I have added this view between textfields and added these lines when `selectedSegmentIndex == 1`

```
[self.pathView removeConstraints:self.pathView.constraints];
[self.pathView setHidden:YES];
```

now i click on the `selectedSegmentIndex==0` then view should reappear.
how can i arrange this view between textfields. When this view is hidden then gap between textfields should be equal accordingly other textfields.

Comment: This kind of situation can be easily handle by `UITableView`. Take a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298961/xcode-ib-uibutton-hidden-but-have-still-buttons-space/26299229#26299229

Answer (score 0):

1> save constraints on some variable before removing it

2> remove your view in between 2 text fields

3> apply that saved constraints again on pathView

4> call `[pathView setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: Should i do remove from Superview?

Comment: Yes I think you should remove the view that you have inserted on segment tap